# How to add a trainable weight to an LSTM in Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I would like to add a trainable weight to my LSTM and when I use the following wrapper provided by Keras, the tensor is initialized but isn't added to the LSTM layer. When I use the same code on Dense layers or convnets it works properly. Is there any other way to add a variable to a recurrent model?

```
def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
    self.output_dim = output_dim
    super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    assert isinstance(input_shape, list)
    # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel',
                                  shape=(input_shape[0][1], self.output_dim),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
    super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

def call(self, x):
    assert isinstance(x, list)
    a, b = x
    return [K.dot(a, self.kernel) + b, K.mean(b, axis=-1)]

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    assert isinstance(input_shape, list)
    shape_a, shape_b = input_shape
    return [(shape_a[0], self.output_dim), shape_b[:-1]]
```

Comment: Where are you trying to "add" to the LSTM layer? Do you really mean "add" as in a mathematical addition?

Comment: No add as in having an additional weight to optimize the dropout rate. The issue is basically that for RNN/LSTM/GRU self.add_weight doesn't work. Keras documentation doesn't mention any restrictions concerning the layer to customize https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

Comment: Dropout rate is not differentiable. It's not possible to optimize it with backpropagation.

Comment: That depends on how you're optimizing the dropout rate. I am using it for Bayesian uncertainty estimation as described in https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/452a/c69a8af5366778f3be178966433f2b6bf70a.pdf